# GTK+ Drop down menu to Toolbar Item

Tags: c++, c, menu, gtk, toolbar

I saw that rekonq's got a toolbar item named preferences like Chromium,which you click and a drop down menu appears!

How can i do something like that on my app?
i presume its a gtk_toolbar_item with  a gtk_menu placed when its clicked but how?

[image: Example of Drop down menu]

Comment: have you looked at this? http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/gtk/GtkCombo.html

Comment: thanks for your help but that is a text entry with a drop down.What i am trying to do is add a menu to a toolbar item when its clicked,like in rekonq or chromium

Comment: Can you post a link to a picture of what you are talking about? Especially if you can show what is missing from @ptomato's answer, as it's not very clear, at least to me.

Comment: @ergosys i dont have reputation to post an image but i will describe you what i want.If you open Chromium click on the preferences button at the top right(the screwdriver) a gtk_menu will appear at the bottom of it.Thats what i want to achieve.You can try and use ptomato's code you will see that even though the button has a menu,it shows it only when the little arrow button it has is clicked and not the button itself.I have tried gtk_menu_tool_button before and thats why it doesnt suit my needs.Hope its clear now :)

Comment: OK, that's a little clearer, although in the chromium I have, there is a wrench in that position, not a screwdriver, but I guess it is the same.  As for the image, you can always put it on one of the free image hosting services and link to it from here.

Comment: Yes i mean a wrench heres an image (found on the net) http://www.blogcdn.com/www.downloadsquad.com/media/2010/06/chrome-menusadf.jpg i hope its clear now and i really hope you can help me with that :) cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, you can do this:

```
GtkToolItem *menubutton = gtk_menu_tool_button_new(NULL, NULL);
gtk_toolbar_insert(GTK_TOOLBAR(toolbar), menubutton, 1);
GtkWidget *menu = gtk_menu_new();
gtk_menu_tool_button_set_menu(GTK_MENU_TOOL_BUTTON(menubutton), menu);
GtkAction *action = gtk_action_new("dropdown-menu", "Dropdown", "Click me", GTK_STOCK_PREFERENCES);
gtk_action_connect_proxy(action, GTK_WIDGET(menubutton));
g_signal_connect(action, "activate", G_CALLBACK(popup_menu), menu);

...

void
popup_menu(GtkAction *action, GtkMenu *menu)
{
    gtk_menu_popup(menu, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, gtk_get_current_event_time());
}
```

Comment: Thats nice,but when i add a "File" menu item to it like that:GtkWidget *file1 = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("File");
gtk_menu_shell_append(menu, file1); i cant see the item but only the drop down menu.Is it possible to hide the bottom arrow thing?

Comment: What bottom arrow thing are you talking about?

Comment: The menu_tool_button has an arrow which when its clicked shows the menu.I am looking for the menu to show when i click the button and not the little bottom arrow it constists of.

Comment: thanks a million times,thats what i was looking for.I will investigate it to know how its done.However when i try to append a "File" menu to the dropdown menu i cant see it in the menu(its like it isnt appended).Heres the additional code i use : GtkWidget *file = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("File"); gtk_menu_shell_append(menu, file);

Comment: oh god,im so dumb,i forgot to use gtk_widget_show_all() :) We work on harder things and i get stuck at the easy one haha thanks a lot for your help :)